# Java Threads can not be re-activated once it is dead. Then how can we pool a Thread to create Thread Pool?

Tags: java, threadpool

How to make a thread alive for a desired period.?
If we somehow make it alive always, doesn't it wasting the resources if there are no tasks..?

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Answer (score 1):

The point of having a pool is keeping the threads alive, so you don't have to create them in the moment that you need them  and they can be reused. The main reason for this, is that creating threads is an expensive process. However, if you have a pool that is larger than your needs you are not optimizing the use of the resources.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you have a thread that is not doing anything, assuming you are not using spinning lock to implement your synchronization primitive (and if you use Java ones, you don't), the thread that has nothing to do should be asleep until it is awoken by the need for it to run.